# create ListNode from Vec with ref to first Node

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, ownership

```rust
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Clone, Debug)]
pub struct ListNode {
    pub val: i32,
    pub next: Option<Box<ListNode>>,
}

impl ListNode {
    #[inline]
    fn new(val: i32) -> Self {
        ListNode { next: None, val }
    }
}


fn create_list(list : Vec<i32>) -> Option<Box<ListNode>> {
    // the code should be written this place
}
```

i have `ListNode` struct like this and dont't want to edit this struct and impl. i get a list of i32 number as Vec and i want to create ListNode that each item in list point next item and at the end return first number

for example get vector like this [1,2,3]
and at the end return object like this (i want to create programmatically and this is hand made)

```rust
ListNode { 
   val : 1,
   ListNode { 
      val : 2,
      next:ListNode { 
          next: None,
          val : 3
      }
   }
}
```

i can't hold first ListNode and return that while dealing with rust borrowing and ownership

`-- Update --`

i am new to rust. so i create an example from the way i want to solve this problem. this example written in typescript

```
class ListNode {
     val: number
     next: ListNode | null
     constructor(val?: number, next?: ListNode | null) {
         this.val = (val===undefined ? 0 : val)
         this.next = (next===undefined ? null : next)
     }
     toString(): string {
        return `ListNode ${this.val}${this.next===null? "" : '  => '+ this.next.toString()}`
     }
 }


function createList(list : number[]) : ListNode|null {
    const firstItem = new ListNode(0,null);
    let second = firstItem;
    for (let item of list) {
        second.next = new ListNode(item,null)
        second = second.next;
    }
    return firstItem.next;
}

const firstNodePointer = createList([1,2,3,4,5])

console.log(firstNodePointer?.toString())
```

Comment: Its probably better to implement a `push()`/`append()` or `prepend()`/`push_front()` function first which your `create_list` function can build off of. Can you include your attempt where you got stuck? Have you read [Learn Rust with Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/)?

Comment: @kmdreko thinks for answering. i added an example from another language that solve this problem. is in rust possible to solve this question like typescript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will create the list in one go.

```rust
fn create_list(list : Vec<i32>) -> Option<Box<ListNode>> {
    let mut head = None;
    let mut current = &mut head;
    for x in list {
        *current = Some(Box::new(ListNode::new(x)));
        current = &mut current.as_mut().unwrap().next;
    }
    head
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the concise example. It helped me on https://leetcode.com/contest/weekly-contest-321/problems/remove-nodes-from-linked-list/